# Configure CloseableHttpClient (4.3) for https and authentication

Tags: java, android, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to connect an android app to my rest server over https.

The server is running with spring boot and spring security with jdbcAuthentication. I'm pretty sure the problem is not coming from the server side.

In the android app, I'm creating a restClient from restTemplate like so :

```
 import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
    import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
    import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
    import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
    import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
    import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
    import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
    import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

    import java.security.KeyManagementException;
    import java.security.KeyStoreException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

    public class RestClient extends RestTemplate {


        public RestClient(String username, String password) {
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;

            try {
                SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = new SSLContextBuilder();
                sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContextBuilder.build());
                CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope("localhost", 443, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
                httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
                getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                Log.e("NoSuchAlgorithmEx", e.getMessage());
            } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                Log.e("KeyStoreException", e.getMessage());
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                Log.e("KeyManagementException", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static <T> T getItem(String url, Class<T> type, String username, String password) {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(username, password);
            return restClient.getForObject(url, type);
        }

    }
```

and I use it like this :

```
MyObject myObject= RestClient.getItem(url, MyObject.class,"username","pasword");
```

If i disable the authentication on the server side using .permitAll() on selectedUrl everything is working great.

If i enable authentication the android app couldn't connect to the server.
"Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type"

On android side i'm using

```
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
```

I think the problem come from the config of my httpClient but I can't see what exacly.

If you guys have any clues...

Comment: you figure this one out?